# Using fastai image augmentation reduced my accuracy

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, classification, fast-ai

I am working on a classifier using the Food-101 dataset. I am trying to react a SOTA score of >=90% using ResNet50. Initially, I was sitting at 75% accuracy. When I included label smoothing, I jumped to a sweet 81% but now when I use fastai’s get_transforms, I dropped to 79%. I also noticed that even though I’m using image augmentation, there wasn’t an increase in my data’s dimensions when I was running the epoch.

Currently, the tfms variable is my augmentation:

```
np.random.seed(42)

path = '/content/food-101/images/train'
file_parse = r'/([^/]+)_\d+\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$'
tfms = get_transforms(do_flip=True,flip_vert=True, max_rotate=10.0, max_zoom=1.1, max_lighting=0.2, max_warp=0.2, p_affine=0.75, p_lighting=0.75)

data = ImageList.from_folder(path).split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.2).label_from_re(pat=file_parse).transform(tfms, size=224).databunch()

top_1 = partial(top_k_accuracy, k=1)
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=[accuracy, top_1], loss_func = LabelSmoothingCrossEntropy(), callback_fns=ShowGraph)

learn.lr_find()
learn.recorder.plot(suggestion=True)
```

[image]

My learning rate also slightly increased from 1.02e-06 to 1.023e-06 when I applied get_transforms() to my model.

I’m running another 5 epochs. The accuracy is low due to label smoothing. This isn’t an issue:

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(5, max_lr=slice(1.023e-06/5, 1.023e-06/15))
learn.save('stage-2')
```

```
epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  accuracy    top_k_accuracy  time
0       6.549849    5.393574    0.009835    0.009835        18:39
1       6.520850    5.373156    0.009835    0.009835        17:57
2       6.468420    5.362789    0.009901    0.009901        17:49
3       6.461528    5.363743    0.009769    0.009769        17:51
4       6.473554    5.364657    0.009901    0.009901        18:05
```

[image]

Now I’m pulling out another learning rate. It jumped to 1.03e-06.

```
learn.unfreeze()
learn.lr_find()
learn.recorder.plot(suggestion=True)
```

[image]

Running another 5 epochs using the new LR and saving it. In this round, the label smoothing does not seem to have the same effect as it did on the earlier run. The model is now showing better accuracy than the earlier 5 epochs:

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(5, max_lr=slice(1e-03/5, 1e-03/15))
learn.save('stage-3')
```

```
epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  accuracy    top_k_accuracy  time
0       3.476312    2.645357    0.491683    0.491683        18:11
1       2.781384    2.276255    0.599670    0.599670        18:22
2       2.356208    1.974409    0.677426    0.677426        18:31
3       2.068619    1.836324    0.732409    0.732409        18:26
4       1.943876    1.789893    0.742310    0.742310        18:20
```

[image]

When I was checking the confusions using this block of code:

```
interp.plot_confusion_matrix()
interp.most_confused(min_val=5)
interp.plot_multi_top_losses()
interp.plot_confusion_matrix(figsize=(20, 20), dpi=200)
```

I got this output about my validation set:

```
15081 misclassified samples over 15150 samples in the validation set.
```

Finally, when I validate the model with the test set, this is what I get:

```
path = '/content/food-101/images'
data_test = ImageList.from_folder(path).split_by_folder(train='train', valid='test').label_from_re(file_parse).transform(size=224).databunch()

learn.load('stage-3')
learn.validate(data_test.valid_dl)
```

**[1.602944, tensor(0.7987), tensor(0.7987)]**

Comment: Please ensure that your image augmented samples actually make sense when compared to training/validation/testing datasets. If the image-augmentation creates samples that are rather unrealistic, you are essentially confusing your model with unrealistic data which will drive the minimum away from what you could expect, given the data fed resembles the distribution of possible input data.

Comment: For instance, say that your problem in reality can have only three outcomes: 0, 1, 2. However, if you train it with 10 outcomes, and your data will never have those other 7 outcomes (3 - 9), your augmentation should be pruned to produce samples such that it only yields 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: How can I ensure something like that?

Comment: First see what are the degrees of freedom in your image-augmentation (the parameters you are changing: angle, size, skew, etc.) and then by some inspection of your data try getting some idea of what values of those parameters just start making them impractical/unreasonable. Once you have an idea of the feasible values of those parameters, now you could adjust the parameters in image-augmentation accordingly.

Comment: Domain knowledge is very important in any kind of model prescription. ML is no exception. What you would gain by inspecting the data and getting clarity about feasible values of the image-augmentation parameters, is in a way domain knowledge.

Comment: You want to have clarity on why you choose these values for the parameters: `max_rotate=10.0, max_zoom=1.1, max_lighting=0.2, max_warp=0.2, p_affine=0.75, p_lighting=0.75`.

Comment: Also, check for class-imbalance in your train/valid/test datasets. Try to **avoid class imbalance**.

Comment: @CypherX My classes are all balanced. As for the parameters, I don't know tbh.  I decided that the more augmentation there is, the better it is.  This is a dataset of 101 different kinds of food.

Comment: @CypherX My validation set is 0.2 of the training set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215000/discussion-between-cypherx-and-oo92).